# How to export mongoose schema using typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have created mongoose schema for user collection now i am trying to import in the controller it shows error `no exported member 'User'. Did you mean 'IUser'?` how to fix this issue ?

user.model.ts

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  userName: string 
  password: string 
}
 const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
   userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
   password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

user.controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { User } from './user.model'
```

Answer (score 9):

For Typescript:

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string; 
  somethingElse?: number; 
};

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true},
  somethingElse: Number,
});

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
export default User;
```

Comment: This looks like an very repetative task

Comment: @NerdioN this is required by typescript to make sure that your schema matches the interface.

Answer (score 0):

When saying export default ...;

when you want to import it just type:

```
import User from "./user.model";
```

**Notice:** User can be anything for example MyUserSchema or anything

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35616428)